# Verilog: Data Transfer using inout ports

Tags: verilog

I have an EEPROM following I2C protocol. My  write operation was fine. While a read operation, SDA being my inout pin, during data transfer from slave, I held the pin in high impedance (Z).I received logic zero correctly but not logic ones.Clock cycles where logic 1 was expected, were showing up high impedance state.

My question is for data transfer from slave to master, should master hold the inout pins in high impedance state? If yes then why is that when data is logic 0, cycles are showing up but when data is 1, still high impedance is observed.

Is there any other value should this inout pin be assigned to so that logic 1 and logic 0 are properly transmitted?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are 'observing' high impedance, I take it this a simulation and not a real circuit.

In these cases, place a pullup on both sda and scl in your testbench (which presumably connects your i2c module with the eeprom model).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am simulating the setup. Perhaps, if I add a pullup, I am losing the acknowledge from slave.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/qpgojk/6 please have a look at the problem

Comment: Please find my code here http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=8elO6

Answer (score 0):

VHDL provides a solution using 9-state logic (`STD_LOGIC` type):

For I2C pins, and any other open-drain pins (weak pull-up), you should drive `H` and `0` (not `Z`).  If any signal is simultaneously driven with `H` and `0`, the `0` will win (as you desire) and you will not get `X` like you would between conflicting `0` and `1`.  And then use the `TO_X01` function when reading the signal, to resolve `H` to `1`.

I would look to see whether Verilog has any logic type which supports weak states.

Comment: Verilog doesn't have weak states. It only has 1, 0, and Z. But it does have weak drivers, which will pull a signal out of Z state but won't cause an error if they conflict with a stronger driver. It also has `tri1` and `tri0` net types with implied pull-up or pull-down, and it also has `pullup` and `pulldown` "gates".

Comment: @ Ben Voigt - How can I assign a value 'H' to a pin?

Comment: @san6086: See ThePhoton's comment... Verilog uses a different approach from VHDL.